# Akka http file logging with logback

Tags: scala, akka, logback, slf4j, akka-http

I am struggling to get logging to work on akka-http with slf4j & logback.
Currently I don't see a logfile being created at all. I would be grateful for a solution, but also how one would "debug" such a situation to find the problem.

I have the dependencies:

```
  val akkaV     = "2.4.16"                                                
  val akkaHttpV = "10.0.1"                                                
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(                                                   
    "com.typesafe.akka"    %% "akka-slf4j"                        % akkaV,     
    "com.typesafe.akka"    %% "akka-http-core"                    % akkaHttpV, 
    "com.typesafe.akka"    %% "akka-http-spray-json"              % akkaHttpV, 
    "ch.qos.logback"        % "logback-classic"                   % "1.1.3"    
  )
```

and in `src/main/resources/application.conf`:

```
akka {                                                                         
  loglevel = DEBUG                                                             
  log-config-on-start = on                                                     
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]                                   
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"                       
  event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]                      
}
```

and finally in `src/main/resources/logback.xml`:

```
<configuration debug="true">                                                                
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">            
        <file>/tmp/myApp.log</file>                                  
        <append>true</append>                                                  
        <encoder>                                                              
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} TKD [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>                                                             
    </appender>                                                                

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">       
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />                                            
    </appender>                                                                

    <root level="DEBUG">                                                       
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />                                           
    </root>                                                                    
</configuration>
```

EDIT: I've added the `debug="true"` flag to the logback file as suggested [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#automaticStatusPrinting), and noticed that the output does not show any lines containing "ch.qos.logback", which seems to indicate that the file is not found.

EDIT2: I had a dependency which was pulling another version of slf4j; appending `excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization="org.slf4j"))` to that dependency in sbt now results in the log file being created. The messages pertaining to that dependency are not logged in the file though, and there are still no entries containing "ch.qos.logback".

Comment: Can you please paste the console logs when you run the program?

Comment: I tried you program and it's logging fine for me.

Comment: @user007 I found the issue, apparently one of the dependencies was pulling in another version of slf4j. Now the log file is produced. However I still don't see any lines containing "ch.qos.logback".